# how to format scala's output from JSON to text file format

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, file-format, string-interpolation

I am using Scala with Spark with below version.

Scala - 2.10.4
Spark - 1.2.0

I am mentioning below my situation.

I have a RDD(Say - JoinOp) with nested tuples(having case classes), for example -

```
(123,(null,employeeDetails(Smith,NY,DW))) 
(456,(null,employeeDetails(John,IN,CS)))
```

This RDD is being created from a Join with two files.

Now, my requirement is to convert this JSON format to text file format without any "Null" and any case class name(here 'employeeDetails').

My desired output is =

```
123,Smith,NY,DW
456,John,IN,CS
```

I have tried with String Interpolation for the same but with partial success.

```
val textOp = JoinOp.map{jm => s"${jm._1},${jm._2._2}"}
```

if I print textOp then it will give me below output.

```
123,employeeDetails(Smith,NY,DW)
456,employeeDetails(John,IN,CS)
```

Now if I try to access nested elements in "employeeDetails" case class with String interpolation, it will throwing error like below.

```
JoinOp.map{jm => s"${jm._1},${jm._2._2._1}"}.foreach(println)

<console> :23: Error : value _1 is not member of jm
```

Here I can understand that, with the above syntax, it's unable to access nested element for "employeeDetails" case class.

What might be the solution for this issue. Any help or point forward would be of much help.

Many Thanks,
Pralay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case classes have field names. So, instead of `._1` you need to use the field name for that position. Assuming the following definition:

```
case class EmployeeDetails(name: String, state: String)
```

you would access it

```
JoinOp.map{jm => s"${jm._1},${jm._2._2.name}"}.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thank you @lulian. It worked. Is there any way by which I can refer all the fields of "employeeDetails" case class without mentioning their names explicitly. Will any special character fetch all the fields ?

Comment: You could use `productElement(n: Int): Any` to retrieve each element of the case class, but you would lose all type information (it returns Any). Usually people prefer using names, since the code is much clearer.

Comment: Thanks Lulian. I have another situation where my RDD is like below. 

(123,(null,employeeDetails(credentails(XYZ,PASS),evaluationReport(80,100)))) 

Here if I use the below syntax, I am unable to access "XYZ" value with  below code 

joinOp.map( op => s"${op._2._2._1}").

Here the last ._1 at the end unable to fetch value from credentails case class. What might be the issue for which nested case class values are not accessible.

Comment: I got it working with below syntax.  joinOp.map( op => s"${op._2._2.<nested tuple class name>.<nested tuple class element name>}")  . Thanks for you assistance Lulian.

Comment: With pleasure, but my name is Iulian, not Lulian (you actually got it right the first time :))

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to print all fields of case class, you may use productIterator to traverse field list.

```
val textOp = JoinOp.map { jm => 
    s"""${jm._1},${jm._2._2.productIterator.mkString(",")}"""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```scala
case class EmployeeDetails(var0: String, var1: String, var2: String)
val data = List((123,(null, EmployeeDetails("Smith", "NY", "DW"))))

data.map {case (num, (sth, EmployeeDetails(var0, var1, var2))) =>
  s"$num,$var0,$var1,$var2"}
```